# Ember JS - ArrayController property returning string literal

Tags: javascript, model-view-controller, ember.js

I have the following code in my EmberJS App

```
// Instantiate the Ember app
var App = Ember.Application.create();

App.Store = DS.Store.extend({
  adapter: DS.RESTAdapter
});
// Mappings for routing
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.route("index", { path : "/"});
    this.route("episode", {path : "/episode"});
});
// Home Page route
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function () {
        return $.getJSON('http://route-to-json/').then(function (data){
            return data;
        });
    }
});

App.EpisodeRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function () {
        return $.getJSON('http://route-to-json/episode/').then(function (data) {
            return data;
        });
    },
    setupController: function (controller, model) {
        controller.set('model', model);
    }
});

App.EpisodeController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
    firstEpisode : function () {
        var self = this;
        this.modelFor('episode').then(function (list) {
            return list.get('firstObject');
        });
    },
    otherEpisodes : function () {
        var self = this;
        this.modelFor('episode').then(function (list) {
            return list.get('content');
        });
    }
});
```

In the episode controller, the first method works completely, and renders

```
<h1> {{ firstObject.programmeName }} </h1>
<time>{{ firstObject.scheduleDate }}</time>
<p>{{ firstObject.summary }}</p>
```

However when trying to use the {{ otherEpisodes }} parameter the function itself is returned as a string literal

e.g. "function...."

And thus when trying to {{#/each}} through it I get an message telling me its trying to loop through the above string and not an Array.

Any help would be appreciated!

Joe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answered my own question by looking at the code should use "content" as the property and not otherEpisodes. D'oh.